# Is a signal sent with kill to a parent thread guaranteed to be processed before the next statement?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

Okay, so if I'm running in a child thread on linux (using pthreads if that matters), and I run the following command

```
kill(getpid(), someSignal);
```

it will send the given signal to the parent of the current thread.

My question: Is it guaranteed that the parent will then immediately get the CPU and process the signal (killing the app if it's a SIGKILL or doing whatever else if it's some other signal) before the statement following `kill()` is run? Or is it possible - even probable - that whatever command follows `kill()` will run before the signal is processed by the parent thread?

Comment: That line doesn't actually send the signal to the "parent of the current thread" - it sends it to the current *process*, which means that the signal could be recieved by *any* of the process's threads that do not have the signal blocked - including the thread you're calling `kill()` from.

Comment: @caf Well, the threads are technically their own processes in linux with their own pids, so that does complicate things. But you could still be right. I'm not all that well-informed about how exactly signals are processed - especially in the face of threads. But the learning continues...

Comment: pthreads in Linux conform to the POSIX thread standard (hence "pthreads").  There is a distinction between processes and threads, even though threads are implemented using individual `task_struct` s inside the kernel.  The upshot is that `getpid()` will return the same value in every thread in the process (the POSIX "process ID"), and `gettid()` (which glibc does not provide a wrapper for) returns the ID of the individual thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals get delivered asynchronously, so you can't expect the thread handling them to handle them immediately; moreover, it will have to do some work to handle it.

And if a sigprocmask() call had masked the signal in all threads, the signal will only be acted upon after it is unmasked.

Signals don't go to any particular thread, unless you have used sigprocmask to mask them from the threads you don't want to get them. Most multithreaded programs do this, as having process-level signals delivered to arbitrary threads is usually not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not guaranteed.

In general, you cannot make any assumptions about the timing of events happening in separate threads (or processes) unless you use an explicit synchronization mechanism (for example, a phtread_mutex or a semaphore).

This is especially true on multi-CPU (or multi-core) systems, where multiple threads can be running literally simultaneously on separate CPUs, but even on a single-CPU system there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Signals sent to a process (thread group) may generally get delivered to any thread, and you generally have no guarantee that the handler will have finished before the `kill` call returns.

If you run

```
kill(getpid(), someSignal);
```

in a multithreaded process then you can only be sure that your sighandler will run before `kill` returns in a very specific scenario, where 
all but the calling threads have `someSignal` blocked (in which case, the sig handler will run from the thread calling `kill`).

See 
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html :

> If the value of pid causes sig to be generated for the sending
>   process, and if sig is not blocked for the calling thread and if no
>   other thread has sig unblocked or is waiting in a sigwait() function
>   for sig, either sig or at least one pending unblocked signal shall be
>   delivered to the sending thread before kill() returns.