# After kill(getpid(), sig), is the signal guaranteed to be delivered before the next statement?

Tags: linux, process, signals

Assuming that you're in a single-threaded process, and that the relevant signal is not blocked or ignored, is it guaranteed that:

```
kill(getpid(), sig);
```

will result in the signal being delivered before the next line of code is executed?

In particular, if the signal is one for which there is no handler and whole default action is to terminate the process (e.g. SIGTERM, SIGALRM), is it guaranteed that the next line of code won't be executed?

I had always assumed that (at least on Linux) the answer was "yes", because I thought that before returning from any syscall the kernel would always check to see if there were any pending signals and deliver them if so.  But I *think* I have observed that (when run on a heavily-loaded, multi-core system) this is not always the case, though this is very hard to reproduce and so I'd appreciate confirmation that I'm not seeing things.

[This question is very similar to [Is a signal sent with kill to a parent thread guaranteed to be processed before the next statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702918) except that that question was asking about multi-threaded processes (for which the answer is definitely "no"), whereas this question is about single-threaded processes.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you're in a single threaded process, [POSIX gives guarantees you this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html).

> If the value of pid causes sig to be generated for the sending
>   process, and if sig is not blocked for the calling thread and if no
>   other thread has sig unblocked or is waiting in a sigwait() function
>   for sig, either sig or at least one pending unblocked signal shall be
>   delivered to the sending thread before kill() returns.

Answer (score 0):

I now think the answer really is "yes".  I had thought previously that the signal was unblocked, but I now realise that may not have been the case, and that this is most likely the cause of the behaviour I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this test code:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sig_atomic_t suspended = 0;

void handle() {
    printf("SIG");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    signal(SIGUSR1, handle);
    printf("BEFO");
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
    //pthread_kill(pthread_self(), SIGUSR1);
    printf("AFTR\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And it seems to always print BEFOSIGAFTR and never BEFOAFTRSIG when i run it in a bash loop on 4 core laptop.

But please note the test is rather flawed in several ways:

- Fact it does work on my PC doesn't mean it's guaranteed (unless it is stated in POSIX documentation)
- The system was not under heavy load during the test
- STDIO does some buffering
- printf() is not signal safe (man 7 signal-safety)